# RowChangeEvent not overriding

Tags: c#

I have a Dataset created with the help of data connections window in my project. When I enter Dataset1 from Solution Explorer, we go to the code line by clicking on the DataTable title that I want to apply the DataRowChangeEvent to. I can override the ColumnChange to the resulting class. But I can't override RowChangeEvent. This event does not appear when I type overlide. What could be the reason for this?
Thanks.

```
public partial class ExampleDataTable
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add `RowChanged` event, from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowchangeeventhandler)

```
private DataTable dataTable;

private void AddHandler(){
   dataTable = new DataTable("dataTable");
   dataTable.RowChanged +=
      new System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_Changed);
}

private void dataTable_Changed(object sender,
System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Row Changed", e.Action,
      e.Row[dataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber]);
}
```

But if you can't do that for some reason and you can basically access `Row` via `ColumnChanged` event

```
private static void Column_Changed(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e )
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dtGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //Do whatever for that row
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columnchanged

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event has already been overridden in the base Dataset.xsd class. If you were to double click on the designer for the data in the .xsd file on a specific table and attempt to manually create the event you'd get a [CS0111](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0111) error *Type 'class' already defines a member called 'member' with the same parameter types*.

The only way to override that event is in your form e.g.

```
someDataSet.SomeTable.RowChanging += SomeTableOnRowChanging;
```